# React component props typescript issue

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a button that can be of 2 variants: contained, outlined

How to make it possible to select only its child colors when specifying the button variant

```
const variants = {
    contained: {
        red: "bg-red-600 text-red-100 active:bg-red-700 hover:bg-red-700",
        disabled: "bg-gray-450 text-gray-100"
    },
    outlined: {
        white: " bg-transparent border-red-100 text-red-100 border-2 hover:text-black hover:border-transparent hover:bg-white",
        disabled: "border-transparent border-2 bg-gray-450 text-white"
    }
}

interface ButtonProps {
    variant?: keyof typeof variants
    onClick?: any
    className?: any
    color?: keyof typeof variants["outlined"]
    size?: keyof typeof sizes
    disabled?: boolean
}


  export const Button: React.FC<ButtonProps> = ({
                                                      variant = "contained",
                                                      color = "red",
                                                      size = "normal",
                                                      disabled = false,
                                                      onClick = null,
                                                      className = "",
                                                      children
                                                  }) => {
    
        return <button
            disabled={disabled}
            onClick={onClick}
            className={`${sizes[size]} ${variants[variant][disabled ? "disabled" : color]} ${className} ${disabled && "cursor-not-allowed"}
            rounded-lg focus:outline-none focus:ring`}>
            {children}
        </button>
    }
```

This is where I wish there was a typeError '"white"' is not assignable to type '"red" | "undefined"

```
 <Button variant={"contained"} color={"white"} size={"normal"} disabled={isDisabled}
                        onClick={() => alert("dsad")}>
                    Test button
                </Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
enum Color {
  White = "white",
  Disabled = "disabled",
}

interface Circle {
  color: Color
}

let c: Circle = {
  color: Color.White
}

console.log(c)
```

From the documentation of typescript enum, there's a lot of other choices.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html